# HttpURLConnection setReadTimeOut() was not working as expected

Tags: java, web-services, http, https, http-headers

I am using HttpURLConnection to connect to the jsp page and configured the readTimeout as 5s.

And delayed the jsp page execution by Thread.Sleep() for 10s.

But don't get the timeout exception instead connection waits for 10s to get the response.

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)jspUrl.openConnection();
con.setReadTimeout(5000);
con.connect();
```

Jsp Page content is shown below.

```
<%
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    JSONArray arrayObj = new JSONArray();
    arrayObj.put(123);
    out.println(arrayObj);  
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

at runtime your jsp page is compiled to a servlet class and up to your `Thread.sleep(10000);` call, some response is already written through the connection. So in the clientside (your httpurlconnection) made already some readings so you didn't fall into a readtimeoutexception

you may have a look at [here](https://www.guru99.com/jsp-life-cycle.html)

you should directly use a `Servlet` to do your testing of timeouts...